# Python return result: TypeError: zip argument #2 must support iteration

Tags: python, typeerror, assert

I receive a TypeError with function return "zip argument #2 must support iteration". The return result is a list e.g. [1.20, 2.51, 6.89] which I compare to expected result list [1.2, 2.5, 6.9]. If the difference is small enough, I pass. Here is a code snippet:

```
def calc():
    last = [1.20, 2.51, 6.89]
    return last
    pass
def check():
    result = calc()
    expected_result = [1.2, 2.5, 6.9]
    for res, exp_res in zip(expected_result, result):  # line of TypeError: zip argument #2 must support iteration
        assert abs(exp_res - res) < 1e-1  # modified from 1e-2
check()
```

What I have tested:
1) I receive this TypeError when I run as presented above in 2 separate functions: 1 function to calculate, and 1 function to test with assert
2) by writing these 2 lists in the same function, that I then call, then this works fine (= no error message). 
But, .. I have to separate in 2 functions.
Any ideas or suggestions would be very appreciated.
Thank you!

Comment: Can't reproduce

Comment: Obviously this is not your real code, because you're _defining_ these functions but never _calling_ them.  Please post your real code.

Comment: @John Gordon: I added call to check() function. Also, my full code is too long, so this snippet shows what is happening. Please let me know if you have clarifying questions.

Comment: @user1739581 "this snippet shows what is happening" No, it does not. We can't fix a problem without seeing the code that is causing it. Please read [ask] and [mcve]

Comment: It's good that you posted a small example.  But this example _does not produce the stated problem_.

Comment: Would it appear that "TypeError: zip argument #2 must support iteration
" is unclear in its explanation of error? My research online is not giving me more clarity on this error.

Answer (score 0):

In a next step, I test if the return can be iterated, since this TypeError mentions that this is not supported. I found some test for the return of function calc(). Here is one example:

```
object_iterator = iter(last)
print object_iterator   # output: True
```

It prints True, so specifying that the return can be iterated. Other tests confirm this.

Does someone have any suggestions for next steps to solve this TypeError?